# URL is not working after parsing in android

Tags: android, parsing

the below one is the url where i am parsing link tags

http://www.mobileapp.pcmac.org/mobile/xml/sisapp.asp?sid=353&pn=news2

in this url the data is

```
 <item>

      **<link>http://www.mcpss.com?PN=&apos;News2&apos;&amp;SubP=&apos;DNewsStory&apos;&amp;gn=&amp;NewsID=17662&amp;ShowNav=&amp;StoryGroup=Current</link>**
    </item>
```

i am parsing the link tag from above data.but when i tried to put that value in a below code it is throwing the following exception:
**HTTP error fetching URL**

```
try {
           String website=list.get(0);
           Document doc = Jsoup.connect(website).get();
           Elements el=doc.getElementsByClass("header");
           Elements atr= doc.select("p span");
           String ss="";
           for(Element s:atr)
               ss+=s.text();
                String text=el.text();
                t1.setText(text);
                t2.setText(ss);
     } catch (Exception e) {
log.d("Error",e.getMessage());

              }
```

if i hard code that link value it is working fine . i need some help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the character entities to their standard form.

```
&apos; becomes `'`
&amp;  becomes `&`
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Comment: i am getting the string correctly and one more thing the link tag is in multiple lines